# Windows 7 Machines do not take reserved IP address from DHCP

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, mac-address

I have NETGEAR router - WGR614 V6 and have mixed network of Linux machines and windows PCs. I use the router's in-built DHCP. I use 'Address Reservation' feature of the router to reserve IPs based on MAC address. All Linux machines obey the DHCP server and take the IP reserved happily. The two windows 7 PCs however never take the IP I have reserved for their MAC addresses. They are adamant about the lowest IP address available in the network and when I check ipconfig it says that its the preferred IP address. Right now I force IP address on windows PCs by starting all Linux machines before the windows PCs, that way it has no choice but to accept the remaining IPs.

I don't know why windows behaves strangely, even my Nokia e72 and my kindle obey the DHCP server and take the IP I want to give them.

Update: wireshark capture:

```
"1","0.000000","0.0.0.0","224.0.0.1","IGMP","V2 Membership Query, general"
"2","0.000002","::","ff02::1","ICMPv6","Multicast listener query (Unknown (0x00))"
"3","3.432039","192.168.122.1","224.0.0.251","IGMP","V2 Membership Report / Join group 224.0.0.251"
"4","27.953035","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 39810 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=512 Len=0 TSV=8065329 TSER=8005328"
"5","27.953147","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","39810 > trusted-web [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=513 Len=0 TSV=8065329 TSER=8065329"
"6","27.953181","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 39810 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=2 Win=512 Len=0 TSV=8065329 TSER=8065329"
"7","27.953365","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","39811 > trusted-web [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32792 Len=0 MSS=16396 SACK_PERM=1 TSV=8065329 TSER=0 WS=6"
"8","27.953393","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 39811 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=16396 SACK_PERM=1 TSV=8065329 TSER=8065329 WS=6"
"9","27.953425","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","39811 > trusted-web [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32832 Len=0 TSV=8065329 TSER=8065329"
"10","52.399210","96.17.182.27","192.168.0.50","TCP","http > 54000 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0"
"11","54.533438","192.168.1.1","224.0.0.1","IGMP","V2 Membership Query, general"
"20","125.440024","::","ff02::1","ICMPv6","Multicast listener query (Unknown (0x00))"
"21","130.336040","192.168.122.1","224.0.0.251","IGMP","V2 Membership Report / Join group 224.0.0.251"
"22","139.505800","0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x824f98c9"
"23","139.506223","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"
"24","139.567859","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<00>"
"25","139.568249","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<00>"
"26","139.568573","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<20>"
"27","139.805670","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"28","139.921827","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.5?  Tell 0.0.0.0"
"29","140.331621","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<20>"
"30","140.332511","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<00>"
"31","140.332902","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<00>"
"32","140.565162","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"33","140.923833","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.5?  Tell 0.0.0.0"
"34","141.095485","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<00>"
"35","141.096006","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<00>"
"36","141.096298","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<20>"
"37","141.166329","192.168.0.1","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x824f98c9"
"38","141.329445","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"39","142.595848","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"40","142.596739","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<20>"
"41","142.597130","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<00>"
"42","142.597432","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB CMIPC<00>"
"43","142.597447","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.5?  Tell 0.0.0.0"
"44","142.598013","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"45","142.599398","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"46","142.599810","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"47","142.600612","0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x824f98c9"
"48","142.603482","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"
"49","143.356855","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"50","144.121244","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"51","144.265745","192.168.0.1","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP ACK      - Transaction ID 0x824f98c9"
"52","145.197853","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"53","145.953702","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"54","146.703652","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"82","163.387239","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"83","164.150880","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"84","164.450586","0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x2d72f0ff"
"85","164.451052","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"
"86","164.915266","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"87","169.688302","0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x2d72f0ff"
"88","169.688767","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"
"89","178.344615","0.0.0.0","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Request  - Transaction ID 0x2d72f0ff"
"90","178.344967","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"
"91","178.667732","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"92","178.674442","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","UDP","Source port: 6646  Destination port: 6646"
"93","180.130523","192.168.1.1","224.0.0.1","IGMP","V2 Membership Query, general"
"94","180.478037","192.168.0.50","224.0.0.251","IGMP","V2 Membership Report / Join group 224.0.0.251"
"95","189.230117","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","UDP","Source port: 6646  Destination port: 6646"
"96","189.367369","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","UDP","Source port: 6646  Destination port: 6646"
"97","190.708141","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"98","190.708438","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.2?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"208","191.414902","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.47?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"209","191.415174","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.48?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"210","191.415486","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.49?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"211","191.415778","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.52?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"212","191.416032","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.51?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"225","191.420126","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.65?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"226","191.420400","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.66?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"227","191.420693","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.67?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"228","192.414873","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.2?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"229","192.415189","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.3?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"285","192.432587","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.62?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"286","192.432914","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.59?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"304","193.945658","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.77?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"305","193.945972","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.78?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"358","194.022111","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.131?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"359","194.784144","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"360","194.910489","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.68?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"423","194.930273","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.131?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"424","195.547118","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"425","195.564098","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<1e>"
"426","195.908116","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.68?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"427","195.908590","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.69?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"486","195.926757","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.128?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"487","195.927038","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.129?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"488","195.927329","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.130?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"489","195.927613","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.131?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"490","196.311469","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<1e>"
"491","196.311912","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"492","196.694122","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"493","196.710373","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"494","196.823403","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"495","197.075840","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<1e>"
"496","197.086302","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.1?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"497","197.137744","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.132?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"498","197.139270","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.133?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"559","197.227269","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.194?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"560","197.232486","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.195?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"561","197.675435","192.168.0.5","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Inform   - Transaction ID 0xd145e4cd"
"562","197.839987","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<1e>"
"563","197.903592","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.132?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"626","197.927429","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.195?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"627","198.604891","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Request Announcement CMIPC"
"628","198.614414","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Host Announcement CMIPC, Workstation, Server, NT Workstation, Potential Browser"
"629","198.901675","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.132?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"692","198.921632","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.195?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"693","200.117292","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Request Announcement CMIPC"
"694","200.289479","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.196?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"695","200.305439","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.197?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"752","200.409653","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.254?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"753","200.678657","192.168.0.5","255.255.255.255","DHCP","DHCP Inform   - Transaction ID 0xd145e4cd"
"754","200.898101","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.196?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"812","200.916091","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.254?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"813","201.630054","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Request Announcement CMIPC"
"814","201.911688","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.196?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"872","201.929785","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.254?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"873","203.143206","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Request Announcement CMIPC"
"874","203.556090","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.50?  Tell 192.168.0.5"
"875","203.556107","Pegatron_12:e6:bf","","ARP","192.168.0.50 is at e0:69:95:12:e6:bf"
"876","204.656014","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Browser Election Request"
"877","205.670641","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Browser Election Request"
"878","206.683424","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Browser Election Request"
"879","207.697248","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","BROWSER","Browser Election Request"
"880","207.956064","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 34410 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 TSV=8245332 TSER=8185331"
"881","207.956170","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","34410 > trusted-web [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=32832 Len=0 TSV=8245332 TSER=8245332"
"882","207.956204","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 34410 [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=2 Win=32768 Len=0 TSV=8245332 TSER=8245332"
"883","207.956391","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","34411 > trusted-web [SYN] Seq=0 Win=32792 Len=0 MSS=16396 SACK_PERM=1 TSV=8245332 TSER=0 WS=6"
"884","207.956421","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","trusted-web > 34411 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=16396 SACK_PERM=1 TSV=8245332 TSER=8245332 WS=6"
"885","207.956455","127.0.0.1","127.0.0.1","TCP","34411 > trusted-web [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=32832 Len=0 TSV=8245332 TSER=8245332"
"886","208.711172","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Registration NB WORKGROUP<1d>"
"887","208.992484","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB WPAD<00>"
```

Comment: Interesting situation. So you are trying or rather okay with creating a static IP for the windows 7 machines? Have you done this in the NIC configuration? Click Start, Control Panel, Network and Internet, Network and sharing center, local area connections, Properties, Assuming your using IPV4 click internet protocol version 4, Then click properties, then click use the following IP address and assign the static IP address. Hope this Helps let me know thanks.

Comment: Also could you please provide the IP scope your using?

Comment: @Branden : 192.168.0.1-192.168.0.50 ... static IPs don't work somehow, I tried that. When I set the static IP the system is unable to connect through WiFi. Also, I don't want to go that route. So I am happy that nobody can set IPs themselves. I restrict services based on IP addresses.

Comment: You're saying that the Windows machines won't take static IP's either? I don't think it's necessarily a DHCP issue if that's the case.

Comment: @Bart - No machine (linux / windows) takes static IP if I give manually. I think because i use WiFi lan, therefore router can dictate the term here. I have set the router to act as DHCP. But that's good because I don't want users to be able to set the static ips.

Comment: It should take a static ip if you assign it to the wireless interface instead of the wired in that case.

Comment: I didn't mean to permanently assign it, just try it for *testing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Wireshark capture the client requests an address multiple times via DHCP, but apparently does not process the response. If you have a firewall solution installed and enabled, please disable it for testing - it is well possible that it is interfering with the DHCP address assignment process.

What address does the client get in the end? If it is 192.168.0.5, the client was holding this address long before the DHCP process completed - it simply keeps the old address as the original DHCP request times out.

Furthermore, a DHCP DISCOVER packet is missing in the capture - when experimenting with DHCP leases please do a "full cycle" by issuing a

```
ipconfig /release
```

followed by

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Comment: While I check as you suggest. I still wonder how come it works with all Linux machines (4 machines) & mobile devices [e72 & Kindle] and not just with 3 windows PCs [2 permanently at the location and one is a guest laptop]!

Comment: I am totally lost with the output of wireshark.. reading help

Comment: Just post it. Summaries will do. BTW: when starting the capture, please apply the packet filter "port 67 or port 68", otherwise you will get a lot of irrelevant data as well.

Comment: @rubydev use netmon as it's much eaier to read, and you will get a better conversation view, but if you can't configure the static IP (as Bart mentioned) and get it to work,this is not a DHCP problem

Comment: @jim: Regarding static IP, I think that is because I am using wifi router and i have set the router to act as DHCP. It seems since the router does not allow the connection if you set static ips.

Comment: How do I post the summary file, its huge. From reading it, it seems router first offers the correct IP (192.168.0.41): here are lines which seems relevant to me (not sure if I am correct):

"23","139.506223","Netgear_7b:55:28","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.41?  Tell 192.168.0.1"

"27","139.805670","192.168.0.5","192.168.0.255","NBNS","Name query NB ISATAP<00>"
"28","139.921827","Netgear_08:c3:d9","","ARP","Who has 192.168.0.5?  Tell 0.0.0.0"

Comment: As it seem from wireshark, the router first offers 192.168.0.41 but in the end gives 192.168.0.5. Not sure why, again as I said its happing only on windows (7) machines.

Comment: From wireshark you can "print" your capture's summary into a text file and paste relevant lines of this (starting with the DHCP DISCOVER from the client) one into the question. Looking at the capture might shed some light on the "why".

Comment: Done. Updated the question.

Comment: Updated the answer. Could you disable the software firewall on your client(s) and post a new capture with a /release /renew cycle as described?

Comment: Yes, it takes 192.168.0.5 which it says is the preferred IP in ipconfig. I will do the steps you have mentioned when I am in office.